# Compute expected value of xsinx

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, means

Can someone shed some light on how to compute the expected value of $x \sin (x)$  and $\cos^2(x)$,as $x\sim U(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

Thanks

Comment: do you know how the expected value is defined? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can compute expected value of a quantity by integrating over all possible states with the probability of being in that state times the value of the quantity of interest in that state:
\begin{equation}
E[y] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} y(a) P(a) da
\end{equation}

In this case $P(a)$ is the pdf of $U(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $y(x) = x \sin(x)$ for the first part, $y(x) = \cos^2(x)$ for the second.

Always happy to help :)

Comment: Understood! But what will be the integration interval? When I tried [−π/2,π/2],it doesn't work!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The integration interval is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Supersaver hint: Information like this is very valuable for people trying to help you out, you should put that in the question!

Comment: Sorry about that! I can't edit my post that's why, I wanted to add some more comments but mistakenly I hit enter button.

Comment: Did you forget to normalize? (ie divide by $\pi$ since the range is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$)

Comment: Yes!I forgot to normalize it

Comment: The subscript $\Omega$ in the integral should read $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Did For some reason I thought $\Omega$ represented the space of all possible outcomes. I don't think $\mathbb{R}$ is necessarily true unless you are dealing with a space of only one random variable.

Comment: Which is the case here, right?

Comment: @Did, sure but I could easily argue I was writing a more general expression from which one can trivially derive a solution. It also seems simpler to look at the sample space in this case since it is much smaller than $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Houeto  You can edit any question you post.

Comment: @KitterCatter OK, let me be brief: $\Omega$ was **wrong**, confusing the target space and the source space. (Likewise, the LHS should read E(y(x)), not E(y).)

Comment: @KitterCatter ,computing the variance will work the same way? From the formula  Var(y(x))=E(y(x)^2)-E(y(x))^2...I got E(y(x)) already.But how about E(y(x)^2)? E[y]=∫y(x)P(x)dx

Comment: Here is the question:

Comment: @KitterCatter ,computing the variance will work the same way? From the formula  Var(y(x))=E(y(x)^2)-E(y(x))^2...I got E(y(x)) already. But how about E(y(x)^2)?Is it  E[y(x)^2]=∫y(x)^2P(x)dx?

Answer (score 1):

Note $E[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) dx$ where $X \sim f$.

So, if $X \sim U(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, then $E[g(X)] = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} g(x) \frac{1}{\pi} dx$.

Now, take $g(x) = x \sin x$ and $g(x) = \cos^2 x$ and do the integrals.

Comment: computing the variance will work the same way? From the formula Var(y(x))=E(y(x)^2)-E(y(x))^2...I got E(y(x)) already. But how about E(y(x)^2)?Is it E[y(x)^2]=∫y(x)^2P(x)dx?